# Finding data where they lie on a straight line between two points

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, math, vectorization

I have a dataframe of length (80 * 125 * 125 = 1,250,000 with 4 columns (cell number: 0 to 1,249,999, x coordinate, y coordinate, and sales).

If we convert the dataframe Sales column into a 3d numpy array in which for every 3rd dimension (each layer of the 80 layers), I have two fixed points in the remaining 2-D array (These two points have the same x and y coordinates and therefore same 2-D numpy indexing in every layer [Point A and Point B below]). Is there any efficient way to find the Sales points (in terms of cell number or numpy element index) that lie on a straight line between these two fixed points starting at point 1 and ending at point 2.

Sample schematic to represent the case:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example with sample input and the expected output.

Comment: Point your favourite search tool at *Bresenham's line algorithm*.